# Execute PostgreSql query in django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

I am trying to execute PostgreSQL query in Djnago but I have some problems. I would like to execute this query:

```
SELECT * FROM data_affectedproductversion 
WHERE vendor_name LIKE 'cisco' 
AND product_name LIKE 'adaptive%security%appliance%' 
AND version='9.1(7)16'
```

It works if I execute it in pgAdmin query editor, but when I try to execute it with django it does not work. I tried something like this:

```
results = AffectedProductVersion.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM data_affectedproductversion WHERE vendor_name LIKE 'cisco' AND product_name LIKE 'adaptive%security%appliance%software' AND version='9.1(7)16';")
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

This is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1339, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1326, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1349, in iterator
    query = iter(self.query)
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 96, in __iter__
    self._execute_query()
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 130, in _execute_query
    self.cursor.execute(self.sql, params)
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong and how can I transform this PostgreSQL query to Django ORM query?

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

My models.py:

```
class DataNist(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
    file  =models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    severity = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    exp_score = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=5, decimal_places=1)
    impact_score = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=5, decimal_places=1)
    cvss_score = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=5, decimal_places=1)
    published_date = models.IntegerField()
    last_modified = models.IntegerField()
    cve = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    cve_url = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.file

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Ranljivosti'


class AffectedProductVersion(models.Model):
    data = models.ForeignKey(DataNist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vendor_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    class Meta:
        index_together = (
            ('vendor_name', 'product_name', 'version')
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.vendor_name + '-' + self.product_name
```

Comment: i don't think there is anything wrong in query

Comment: post your model code

Comment: I add it to my question @c.grey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run custom SQL query using cursor.
Like this

```
from django.db import connection
raw_query = "SELECT * FROM data_affectedproductversion 
WHERE vendor_name LIKE 'cisco' 
AND product_name LIKE 'adaptive%security%appliance%' 
AND version='9.1(7)16'"

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(raw_query)
cursor.fetchall()
```

For more info see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you can't do that using Django ORM. Should be something like:

```py
results = AffectedProductVersion.objects.filter(vendor_name__icontains='cisco', product_name__icontains='adaptive%security%appliance%', version__icontains='9.1(7)16')
```

or you look for the exact values removing the `__icontains` lookup.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this saves someone a few minutes

The problem is the raw SQL string

```
"SELECT * FROM data_affectedproductversion WHERE vendor_name LIKE 'cisco' AND product_name LIKE 'adaptive%security%appliance%software' AND version='9.1(7)16';"
```

has string formatting operators: `%s` and `%a` in it.

So the `raw` method is expecting a `params` argument (with a tuple of what to replace those formatting operators with). When the amount of elements on the tuple is smaller than the amount of operators, it throws an `IndexError`.

You need to escape `%` with `%%`, i.e.

```
"SELECT * FROM data_affectedproductversion WHERE vendor_name LIKE 'cisco' AND product_name LIKE 'adaptive%%security%%appliance%%software' AND version='9.1(7)16';"
```

**References**:

1. [Old String formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting)
2. [Passing parameters into raw()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw)